# How to linearize these constraints in scheduling optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I have a mixed integer programming problem as below

$$\underset{{\bf w}_k }{\max}\sum_{k=1}^K x_k\alpha_k \log_2(1+\gamma_k)$$
subject to
$$\sum_{k=1}^K x_k||{\bf w}_k||^2_2\le P$$

$$x_k\in\{0,1\}$$

How can we deal with the objective and the first constraint to have an efficient solution?

Comment: [This link](https://www.leandro-coelho.com/linearization-product-variables/) explains how to linearize the product of a binary and continuous variable. That may help, but I think you’re going to have issues because the norm of $\mathbf{w}_k$ is squared.

Comment: Even if the norm is not squared, it’s creating issues

Comment: I guess both $x_k$  and $\mathbf{w}_k$ are variables, right?

Comment: @ThePheromoneKid, yes they both are variables.

Comment: It is definitly not an easy problem and depends also on the relation of $\lambda_k$ and $\mathbf{w}_k$. Maybe you can clarify?

Comment: @ThePheromoneKid, I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is complicated due to the binary variables and the will probably be no quick and easy answer.

For the "weighted sum rate maximization" problem, which is basically your problem without these variables, an iterative algorithm has been proposed in https://authors.library.caltech.edu/19444/1/Tan2009p110922009_Ieee_International_Symposium_On_Information_Theory_Vols_1-_4.pdf.

The binary variables of your approach can be interpreted as users that are selected or excluded from a wireless transmission. Such an approach has been made in https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/32242541.pdf